# How can I set a "priority" for marking records in a database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that currently finds duplicates and it works fine. The issue is that some records have a field called DS which can have 2 possible values. VOTER or DMV.

When looking for duplicates, if one is found, I want to delete the VOTER record not the DMV record. Can this easily be done?

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *,
                Row_Number() OVER(partition BY fips_county_code, last, suffix, first, birthdate Order by (select null)) AS Rn
         FROM   WORK)
UPDATE cte
SET    DUPES = 'D'
WHERE  RN > 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put DS in your order by clause.  DMV comes before Voter.  If both exist, DVM will be RN 1, Voter will be RN 2.

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *,
                Row_Number() OVER(partition BY fips_county_code, last, suffix, first, birthdate Order by DS ) AS Rn
         FROM   WORK)
UPDATE cte
SET    DUPES = 'D'
WHERE  RN > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `order by` in your `row_number()` to include a `case` expression to give `'DMV'` higher priority like so:

```
;with cte as (
  select *
    , rn = row_number() over(
        partition by fips_county_code, last, suffix, first, birthdate 
        order by case when ds = 'dmv' then 0 else 1 end asc
        )
  from work
)
update cte
set    dupes = 'D'
where  rn > 1;
```